# how to make the http call in react js to java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reactjs

hi i am learning reactjs, i don't no how to load the data from the server to reactjs to bind the data to the static content rendering using react js , could any one help me out with this problem for me

Thank You

Sriram.U

Comment: [React's tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) covers simple comment box example with a backend. Generally, you'll want to use REST API to communicate between frontend and backend.

Comment: thanks @kujira it would be great if you have any code based examples, so that I can comprehend better.

Comment: The [tutorial comes with backend code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial), and goes you through how to write the frontend (React). I understand you are feeling tedious to do the tutorial, but it has perfect materials to make you comprehend. Try skimming through the code/tutorial first, and if that doesn't click in, then try the tutorial.

Comment: thanks @Kujira i will try this out